# React assign value conditionally

Tags: reactjs

```js
let productCount = 1
let subItemLength = 1

let [isFetching, setIsFetching] = (productCount === subItemLength) ? ([isFetching, setIsFetching] = null) : ([isFetching, setIsFetching] = useInfiniteScroll(fetchMoreListItems))
```

im trying to assign a value to [isFetching, setIsFetching] conditionally but its not working and im getting this error:

"React Hook "useInfiniteScroll" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render"

Answer (score 0):

Can not call any [hooks conditionally like](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

```
// won't work
if (true) {
  useEffect(() => ..., [])
}
```

You can pass some condition inside *useInfiniteScroll* hook.